# Templated return type inferred from type of forwarded function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function, perfect-forwarding

I am attempting to write a header file containing a function that calls a function within main.cpp, forwarding an arbitrary number of parameters. The return type of this code needs to match the return type of the forwarded function. In an attempt to achieve this, I wrote the following dummy program, but I am unable to get this to compile. I would be grateful for some help:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double f(double x, int params) {
    return 1;
}

template <typename func, typename... Args>
double test(std::function<func(double, Args...)> predicate, Args&&... params){
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    int dummy = 1;
    double result = test(&f, dummy);
    std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (clang++-3.8) gives the following error:

```
test.cpp:15:18: error: no matching function for call to 'test'
        double result = test(&f, dummy);
                    ^~~~
test.cpp:9:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'function<type-parameter-0-0 (double, type-parameter-0-1...)>'  against
      'double (*)(double, int)'
double test(std::function<func(double, Args...)> predicate, Args&&... params){
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question by removing all unnecessary code and comments and adding the exact error message your compiler gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto test(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
test(f, j, dummy);
```

In C++14 you can write this more simply as:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) test(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, what I failed to mention in my post was that the header introduces a new variable that gets passed to the forwarded function. I have tried `template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto test(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(double, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
  double x = 3.2;
  return std::forward<F>(f)(x, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}` but I now get the compiler error `test.cpp:16:42: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(double, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {`

Comment: @AlexD: `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(42., std::forward<Args>(args)...))` or `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::declval<double>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, got it now :)

Comment: @AlexD: In the future, please ask questions that are representative of your actual problem, so that you can use the answer to derive a solution :-)